# Identifying the current cell in a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure if this is possible, but it should be. I want to apply a formula to an entire column `B` without having to change the row for each formula manually.

How would I write a single formula that takes the current cell (say `B2`) and knows that since it is in row 2 to take `A2` as an input, or when it is in cell `B7` to look at `A7`...

The formula for `B2` would be `=IF(A2="Yes","Please explain here")` but applied to the entire column `B` with a single formula.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've already done it. Use `=IF(A2="Yes","Please explain here")`

Unless you specify otherwise, (eg by using a `$` in your reference) references in Excel are relative, so the `A2`, when entered in a formula in `B2` really means "One cell to my left." If you copy that cell and paste it into the whole column or just drag the cell down using the point on the bottom right corner, you'll see that the references in each row have been updated.

If you'd used `$A$2` instead, you'd have made an absolute reference, and the references wouldn't change -- they'd always point to `$A$2`. You can also refer to `$A2` or `A$2` to make the column absolute and the row relative, or vice versa.

The `$A:$A` in Chris's (correct) answer is a special case. It's an absolute reference to column A. When you put a single-column (or single-row) range in an expression where only a single value is expected, excel picks the cell from the range in the same row (or column) as the cell being evaluated. It's pretty because all the formulas in your column look the same, but you can easily get in the habit and accidentally do something like `=max($A:$A,$D:$D)` instead of `=max($A2,$D2)`, which will not give the expected result, so I usually try to avoid it.

In general, if you're using `INDIRECT` you're doing something wrong. The performance implications are nothing compared to the maintenance implications.

Comment: as follows from OP Q, **it should be a single formula for entire row** (and your solution change formula - you will get `=IF(A2="Yes","Please explain here")`, then `=IF(A3="Yes","Please explain here")` and so on..). Read attentively. And of course we all know about relative formulas and `$` sign

Comment: @simoco Hi simoco - I read it differently. I thought he was trying to avoid the work of rewriting the formula, and assumed he was very new to Excel. If he was just aesthetically offended by the changing formula, than chris's answer is correct, or he could use R1C1 style. No offense to you intended - I usually don't downvote, but using indirect is just plain bad advice. I wasn't trying to start a war - in fact I looked through your answers and found one to upvote as a balance, as is my practice.

Comment: Btw, `Indirect` do what OP wants, so I think my answer is correct. I agree that Chris asnwer is better, but this doesn't mean that my answer is uncorrect

Comment: maybeWeCould was right. I'm new to formulas in Excel and didn't know the difference between relative and absolute referencing. Thanks to everyone I learned a lot just from this small thread.

Answer (score 2):

A much simpler approach is to use

```
=IF($A:$A="Yes","Please explain here")
```

Note that using `INDIRECT` creates a Volitile function, which has performance implications.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("A" & ROW())="Yes","Please explain here")
```

Answer (score -1):

1 column to the left of current;

```
=IF(INDIRECT("RC[-1]",0)="Yes","Please ...")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed! Sorry but I'm new and can't up-vote yet.